I have an issue with the gradle files
Current java version is 17 and the gradle version downloaded is 8.11.1 Error message and the files are below:
Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:9:1: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart'.
import 'carousel_controller.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:48:15: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart'.
: CarouselController() as CarouselControllerImpl,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.


Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Use compatible plugin versions
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

gradle-wrapper
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


build.gradle/app
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> localProperties.load(reader) }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode') ?: '1'
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName') ?: '1.0'

//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    namespace "com.example.kiralik_kaleci" // Keep only one namespace here
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion = "27.0.12077973"
    buildToolsVersion "35.0.0"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kiralik_kaleci"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version '8.1.0' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.20" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
}

include ":app"


I have tried almost every version of gradle and java and still could not fix it. Everytime I change versions I get a different error, this happened after I upgraded android studio I asssume

i have been there days ago and tried mixing versions trying to figure out
maybe try to make AGP compatible  with gradle version
see this Link
and this Compatibility Matrix for jvm and gradle
and maybe edit this line
 kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

to  
kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "17"
        }


I think problem is not in your android configuration. You are using two imports for CarouselController. You can check the code of flutter where you use CarouselController and delete one of it might fix the problem

The main problem that I had was android:name line in the AndroidManifest.xml was placed wrong

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
